# is there a way to set custom property using groovy in ready API

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I am getting  'EmployeeID' Value from one of my API Response using groovy. Now i want to set that value in custom properties using groovy so that i can reuse it in my post API Calls. Is there a way we can achieve this in ready API or using groovy script

Comment: Yes you can do that. Provide more details on from where you want to set the value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, it depends at which level you want to set your property

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("my_prop", my_value) // at test case level
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("my_prop", my_value) // at test suite level
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("my_prop", my_value) // at project level
```

note that "my_value" must be a string, so you may need to cast it : my_value.toString()

Comment: Thanks alot that's exactly i was looking for.